# Filter scroll starts before it reaches the top div

Tags: jquery, scroll, fixed

How can I get this function starts 20px before reaching the top?
As it is now, I have a fixed head that is 20px hight and and the function starts not until it reaches the top of main page.

```
$(function() {
    var top = $('#filter').offset().top,
        footTop = $('#outside_footer_wrapper').offset().top,
        maxY = footTop - $('#filter').outerHeight();
    console.log(top , footTop, maxY);
    $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(y);
        if (y > top) {
            console.log('mayor');
            $('#filter').addClass('fixed').removeAttr('style');
            if (y > maxY-130){
                var min = y - maxY + 130;
                console.log('mayor y menor', min);
                $('#filter').css('top','-'+min+'px');
            }
        } else {
            $('#filter').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/6r3WZ/5/)

Comment: You want it to be fixed after reach the bottom of the div not the top ? Can you add an example on jsfiddle

Comment: We can't help without the CSS. As mentioned, can you please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: No, want it to be fixed 20px before it reaches the top.
It now becomes fixed only when it reaches the top.

Comment: exactly how do I print the variable that contains the value of 20px?